# java script template parsing undefined when creating dynamic tr

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

I am creating an email template using javascript literal to parse value of javascript in template.

```
    <table style="border:none;">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th>Service Name</th>
          <th align="right" style="width:100px;">Quantity</th>
        </tr>`
        + req.body.serviceObj.forEach(element => {
            `<tr>
                <td>${element.selectedService.Service}</td>
                <td align="right" style="width:100px;">${element.selectedService.Quantity}</td>
            </tr>`
        }); +
        `</tbody>
    </table>
```

Above I am looping over `req.body.serviceObj` and creating dynamic tr. All template upto this logic works. But after this logic parsing stops. And only template above is returned with `<tr><td>undefined` for dynamic tr. `req.body.serviceObj` is an array of `selectedService` objects.

```
req.body.serviceObj:
    [{
        selectedService: 
        {
            ServiceId: 13, 
            Service: "OVERLOAD", 
            Description: "Container Overload", 
        …} 
    }]
```

Comment: Please can you add a code on how to return in foreach. I always use Object.keys().map. So If you can paste your idea for code snippet on returning multiple tr from foreach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `forEach` does not return anything, use `map` instead
2. You have an unwanted `;` after it
3. Since you're using templating quotes (```), you can use `${...}` to insert JS into it
4. Since `map` returns an Array, you'll want to convert it to a String with `join`

Here is a demo:

```js
// Just for the demo
const req = {
  body: {
    serviceObj: [
      {selectedService: {Service: 'Netflix', Quantity: 2}},
      {selectedService: {Service: 'YouTube', Quantity: 1}},
      {selectedService: {Service: 'Amazon Prime', Quantity: 5}}
    ]
  }
};

document.body.innerHTML = `
  <table style="border:none;">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th>Service Name</th>
        <th align="right" style="width:100px;">Quantity</th>
      </tr>
      ${
        req.body.serviceObj.map(element => {
          return `<tr>
              <td>${element.selectedService.Service}</td>
              <td align="right" style="width:100px;">${element.selectedService.Quantity}</td>
          </tr>`;
        }).join('')
      }
      </tbody>
  </table>
`;
```